# How can I access a component from a MudDialog?

Tags: c#, dialog, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

The following code returns an IDialogReference:

```
IDialogReference myComponentDialog = DialogService.Show<MyComponent>("MyComponent", parameters, options);
```

I can't pass a reference as an argument, so I'm hoping there is some way to extract "MyComponent from the IDialogReference.

This way I can call a method from MyComponent.

Comment: var myComponentDialog = 
await DialogService.ShowAsync<MyComponent("MyComponent", parameters, options);("Delete Server", parameters);
var result = await dialog.Result;

You can pass the dialog result. They can be primitive or complex types.

Comment: `var component = (MyComponent)myComponentDialog.Dialog;`

Answer (score 1):

The MudDialog does not internally maintain a component reference to the component used as content.

If you really must communicate TO the content component FROM outside the dialog, then you could use an EventBus.

1. Create a Wasm Event Bus: https://github.com/cpear/BlazorComponentBus
2. Publish the event from outside the MudDialog
3. Subscribe to the event from your content component
4. Respond to the event in the content component by calling the method that you'd like to call from outside the MudDialog.

Opinion:

When a MudDialog is shown then the only interaction should be with that UI component, so the user should not be able to initiate an activity from outside the content component, so not sure why you'd need to send a message to an active dialog from outside.

Perhaps that dialog should be updated based on an event (maybe SignalR from server or from a wasm background service).  In which case, your content component could subscribe directly to that event instead of another component outside the dialog handling the event and then trying to call a method on the active dialog content component.